# Page speed nginx server

Tags: caching, nginx, mod-pagespeed

My nginx server is running with pagespeed but every day I have some problems with cache. The problem is that after some time the scripts loaded in my site returns 404 error. When i look into the cache directory I find a new file named !clean!time!, I supose, like the name suggest, that the cache need to be cleaned. After manual clean and restart server all comes to work. Some one can explain me this behavior? Can I set an "auto-clean cache" on nginx configuration? Thanks

Comment: what's in your error logs?

Comment: After looking some error logs one of the more  frequently warning about pagespeed is `...Resource based on [resource_original_link] but cannot access the original`

Comment: does the problem reproduce with modpagespeed off?

Comment: The problem is the cache used by pagespeed, if I turn off pagespeed I've no problem